# Selenium Web Scraping Error: Element Not Interactable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, compiler-errors

As you can see below that am trying to build small `APP` that login `Twitter` but i keep getting an error

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys
import Keys import time


class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get("https://twitter.com/login/")
        time.sleep(3)


email = bot.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]')
password = bot.find_element_by_name('session[password]')

email.clear()
password.clear()
email.send_keys(self.username)
password.send_keys(self.password)
password.send_keys(keys.RETURN)
```

Output:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

Comment: did you try using wait conditions? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Hi Omar, welcome to Stack Overflow community, kindly please share the `HTML` source for the element, also please note that error is usually resolvable by using `implicitlyWait`

Comment: The problem is not a waiting issue. He is selecting the wrong element on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code does not generate the stated error given when copy and pasted. I had to correct lines 6 and 22 to get it to run properly. Please be careful when putting code on here as it will discourage answers.

Your problem is that the `session[username_or_email]` is not a unique element on the Twitter login page. There are actually 3 elements with that name. [image: three elements with the target name]

You need to select the one which is actually interactable, **which is the 2nd `session[username_or_email]` on the page**. Same thing with `session[password]` Your code selects the first element on the page with that name. You are seeking the 2nd element on the page with that name.

You must change

```
email = bot.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]')
password = bot.find_element_by_name('session[password]')
```

to

```
email = bot.find_elements_by_name('session[username_or_email]')[1]
password = bot.find_elements_by_name('session[password]')[1]
```

**The fully working code with all modifications**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Chrome()
    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get("https://twitter.com/login/")
        time.sleep(3)

        email = bot.find_elements_by_name('session[username_or_email]')[1]
        password = bot.find_elements_by_name('session[password]')[1]

        email.clear()
        password.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

Omar = TwitterBot('Omar Username', 'Omar password')
Omar.login()
```